# On Homotopy Equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If a space X is homotopic equivalent to Y and X is contractible, prove that Y is contractible

I know that since X is contractible the identity map is nullhomotopic and since X,Y are homotopic equivalent then the composite fg is homotopic to the constant map of X and the composite map gf is homotopic to the constant map of Y

And after that I'm kind of lost

Comment: homotopic is a notion we use for maps, you probably mean $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: I'm sorry yes, I meant to change that and I forgot, I edited it

Comment: Hint: carefully write down exactly what the statements "$X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$", "$X$ is contractible" and "$Y$ is contractible" mean, in terms of the various functions whose existence they assert and give the domain and codomain of each of these functions. (Also please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your question.)

Comment: I have done exactly that and I dont know where to go from there